# How to use arraylist in observable?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

my first day to use Rxjava and it worked successfully in one string and now i tried to use it in arraylist but application crash i dont know how to work with that and this is my code using arraylist i used rxjava and rxandroid

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ArrayList<String>mylist=new ArrayList<String>();
    mylist.add("ahmed");
    mylist.add("mohameed");
    mylist.add("ibrahem");
    rx.Observable<ArrayList<String>> observerable=rx.Observable.just(mylist);
    Observer<ArrayList<String>>observer=new Observer<ArrayList<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Log.e("completed","completed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.e("error",e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(ArrayList<String> list) {
            Log.e("array is", String.valueOf(list));
        }


    };
    observerable.subscribe((Action1<? super ArrayList<String>>) observer);
}
}
```

Comment: How about showing actual error ?

Comment: com.example.begroup_web_0.rxjava.MainActivity$1 cannot be cast to rx.functions.Action1

Comment: Its self explainatory isnt it?